# How to add a price list for a specific user wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a price list for a specific user for example :

user 1 see the price list 1
user 2 see the price list 2

Comment: Very vague question.. no information on what exactly you're using. Most likely WooCommerce. No information on what you have tried so far and how it didn't work like you expected, or at what point you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use woocomerce one approach is too hook with the `woocommerce_get_price` filter like below (use this filter in your theme `functions.php`):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'mlnc_price_user_based', 10, 2);

function mlnc_price_user_based($price, $product) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $price;

        //check if the user has a role of dealer using a helper function, see bellow
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator'){
            //give user 10% of
            $price = $price * 0.5;
        }

    return $price;
}
```

In this example I filtered users by user roles

Anyway you have to provide more info like @Damocles mentioned